# WSDL to fixed text conversion is not padding character in IIB?

Tags: mapping, esb, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus, dfdl

I have a requirement in which conversion of xml to text which is fixed. The DFDL Test Serialize model is padding character if length is less than specified length of field. When running flow after mapping padding character is not showing. If in xml field value is hello after padding should be helloAAAAAAAAA following is dfdl source and mapping source.

[image: flow] [image: mapping] [image: test model] [image: output1] [image: output2]

Comment: How are you testing this? Where are you looking at the output?

Comment: And btw in your message def, you have the padding character '*', and the body_elem1 is right justified, so these will not look like your requirement for sure.

Comment: Receiving request and web service and transforming it into dfdl fixed length format and than output node connected to javacompute to perform some action kindly go through images which are attached

Comment: and in java compute padding character is not coming when performing operation

Comment: You should look at the actual output, net in the debug tools. The padding character is added when the message is serialized on output.